# How can I change the --android-platform in Qt Creator to not be android--1 in debug mode?

Tags: android, qt, qt-creator, android-sdk-tools, qt-necessitas

I'm trying to run a new Qt Quick application on my android device through Qt Creator.  However, Qt Creator keeps using Android API version *1* whereas I would like it to target an Android API version 10 ( aka Android 2.3.3).

When I run Debug->Start Debugging and then select either an `armeabi` or `armeabi-v7a` on my physical device and emulators, Qt mysteriously continues to target `android--1`:

`"C:\Qt\5.4\android_armv5\bin\androiddeployqt.exe" --input C:/dev/qc/build-qc_mobile-Android_for_armeabi_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_4_0-Debug/android-libqc_mobile.so-deployment-settings.json --output C:/dev/qc/build-qc_mobile-Android_for_armeabi_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_4_0-Debug/android-build --deployment bundled --android-platform`**`android--1`**`--jdk C:/jdk1.8.0_05 --ant C:/eclipse/plugins/org.apache.ant_1.9.2.v201404171502/bin/ant.bat`

How can I configure my project to target a different android version when debugging?

```
My Qt creator instance is:
Qt Creator 3.3.0 (opensource)
Based on Qt 5.4.0 (MSVC 2010, 32 bit)

Built on Dec 8 2014 at 15:24:21

From revision d36c4d87db
```

FYI, deploying a release-mode APK to my device does work.  I'm just hoping to get debug-mode working.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should go to **Projects > Build Android APK > Details** for configuring deployment settings. There is an option named **Android Build SDK**. Just select the appropriate Android API version.

Also to create an APK package, select the **Bundle Qt libraries in APK** option :

[image]

You can also select **Create Templates** to create the manifest file to set application settings like icon, name, ...

Comment: I don't see `Build Android APK`   When I click on projects, I see this http://i.imgur.com/Cytj3D0.png  .

Comment: I can see `Build Android APK` in the image you provided. Are you sure you have Qt Creator 3.3 ?

Comment: Oh my.  I am blind.  Thank you Nejat.

Comment: @Nejat I don't have anything next to Android Build SDK.The combobox seems to be passive

Comment: The selection of SDK api level combo box is deactivited... in Build Android APK

Comment: @Nejat the combo box seems to be disactivated. By clicking nothing happens. Could you give hints?